# MS Access query to open form if any value in a field matches any item in a list box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a "Search" form in Access with a number of controls that can be selected or filled out, enabling the user to bring up a datasheet with a list of records matching the parameters they've entered.

Everything works fine, except for one control: a multi-select list box in which the user can select multiple items. I ideally want to use the list box to search a text field ("Sectors") from a table ("Entity_Activity"). This "Sectors" text field can either be blank, or can hold a single item, or can hold a list of items separated by semi-colons. The idea is that if ANY of the list box items appear in the text field, it should return that record in the datasheet.

I'm really struggling to make this work. My current attempt is as follows.

I have a query that runs the search. Here's a simplified version of it (I've retained the relevant parts):

```
SELECT Entity_Activity.[Activity ID], Entity_Activity.[Project ID], Entity_Activity.Sector, Entity.Activity.[Activity Status], [List_Activity Status].[Activity Status], Entity_Project.[Project ID]
FROM [List_Activity Status] INNER JOIN (Entity_Project INNER JOIN Entity_Activity ON Entity_Project.[Project ID] = Entity_Activity.[Project ID]) ON [List_Activity Status].[Activity Status ID] = Entity_Activity.[Activity Status]
WHERE (Entity_Project.[Project Number] Like "*" & Forms!Query_Activities!txtProjectNo & "*" Or Forms!Query_Activities!txtProjectNo Is Null)
And ((Entity_Activity.Sector Like "*" & Forms!Query_Activities!MySectors & "*") OR (Forms!Query_Activities!MySectors Is Null));
```

I then have a text box ("mySectors") that uses VBA to collect any of the items selected in the list box and separate them with "* OR Entity_Activity.Sector Like *". I was hoping this would be brought into the query (at the "Forms!Query_Activities!MySectors" part) and allow it to change the SQL parameters according to what the user has chosen in the list box.

```
Private Sub lstQuerySector_Click()
    Dim oItem As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

iCount = 0

If Me!lstQuerySector.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each oItem In Me!lstQuerySector.ItemsSelected
            If iCount = 0 Then
                sTemp = sTemp & Me!lstQuerySector.ItemData(oItem)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            Else
                sTemp = sTemp & "* OR Entity_Activity.Sector Like *" & Me!lstQuerySector.ItemData(oItem)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If
            Me!mySectors.Value = sTemp
        Next oItem
    Else
        Call clearSectorListBox
        Me!mySectors.Value = Null
    End If

End Sub
```

This works fine if I just have a single item selected in the list box. However, if I select more than one item, no results appear.

Is there a way to fix this, or are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the already built-in search features of the datasheet view? Can you not just click on the down arrow of a column header and filter that way?

Comment: Yes, but there are a couple of reasons why I'm not doing it that way. Firstly, the users want to have a "one-stop shop" for their searching, i.e. they'd like it all to happen within a single search form (and therefore do not want to do further filtering, etc. if possible). Secondly, the field in question ("Sectors") is a single text field that is made up of a list of different items (i.e. sectors) delimited by semi-colons. Therefore the filter in the datasheet view does not allow users to click on a specific sector from a list, unlike the list box. Perhaps this wasn't a sensible way to do it!

Comment: Loop through listbox selection and build array list for use with `IN()`. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html. Wait, field is semi-colon delimited text?!?! Well, then need to build criteria with OR operator between: `field LIKE '*item1*' OR field LIKE '*item2*' OR etc`. Still have to loop through listbox selection.

Comment: Don't use dynamic parameterized query. Build the criteria dynamically with VBA and apply to form or report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.

Comment: Just to confirm, Sectors is not a multi-value field - just a text string? It is seldom sensible to store data as delimited string. Multi-value field might be reasonable in this situation but I never use them.